# Can a HTTP Server send multiple files in a structured file directory to browser

Tags: php, html, http

Can a web server push multiple downloads to a browser and ask it to download all the files and place them in the local storage in a pre-provided directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You have two main options.

1. Serve a .zip file with the directory structure inside it.
2. Your web page can initiate multiple downloads - although the browser will warn the user.